# Unable start mongoose im in ubuntu. process crashes

Tags: ubuntu, ejabberd, mongoose-im

## mongooseimctl live

[image]

Does this mean I dont have enough physical memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it seems like you ran out of memory. Try decreasing the default heap size or just limit the number of processes at the time you start mangoose.